# Dijkstra algorithm optimization/caching

Tags: php, caching, optimization, dijkstra

I have the following **Dijkstra algorithm** with 3 input variables (start, stop and time). It takes about 0.5-1s to complete. My hosting provider says it's using too much resources and I should implement some caching mechanism. My question is, how?

Because I have 3 variables, if only one of them changes - the whole result is different (because I have some additional statements with time, nevermind). So how to implement some caching mechanism or do some optimisation?

I have **1700 nodes**.

```
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require("../includes/global_variables.php"); ?>
<?php
    // Function to put "maxValues" into time (in my case 10 000 because I know it can't take longer than that from source to end node)
    function array_push_key(&$array, $key, $value) {
        $array[$key] = $value;
    }

    // Start the counter
    $timeM = microtime(); $timeM = explode(' ', $timeM); $timeM = $timeM[1] + $timeM[0]; $start = $timeM;

    // Get provided values
    $startStop = $_GET["start"];
    $endStop = $_GET["end"];
    $startTime = $_GET["time"];

    // Initialize arrays
    $time = array();
    $previousNode = array();
    $allStops = array();

    // [5] = 119 --> You can get to stop no. 5 by line no. 119
    // line to source node is 0
    $lineToThisStop = array();
    $lineToThisStop[$startStop] = 0;

    // Populate arrays
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT stop_id FROM db_stops", $connection);
    potvrdi_unos($result);
    $counter = 0;
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push_key($time, $rows["stop_id"], 10000);
        array_push($allStops, $rows["stop_id"]);
        // Locate startStop in the allStops array to unset it few lines later
        if ($rows["id"] == $startStop) {
            $poz = $brojac;
        }
        $counter++;
    }

    // Set starting time to starting stop
    $time[$startStop] = $startTime;
    // Set it activeNode
    $activeNode = $startStop;

    // Unset it in allStops array (so it doens't have to be checked later)
    unset($allStops[$poz]);
    $allStops = array_values($allStops);

    // I can put "while (true)" because all nodes are connected in "one piece", there is NO UNCONNECTED nodes
    while (true) {       
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT route_id, next_stop FROM db_stop_times WHERE stop_id = $activeNode", $connection);
        potvrdi_unos($result);

        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {         
            // Draw paths from active node to all other (connected) stops
            $nextStopArray = $rows["next_stop"];

            // nextStopArray is something like "0,34,123,3123,213" - those are all stops from current, active node/stop
            $nextStopArray = explode(",", $nextStopArray);

            // sometimes it's just "4" to convert it into array
            if (!is_array($nextStopArray)) {
                $nextStopArray[0] = $nextStopArray;
            }

            for ($p = 0; $p < sizeof($nextStopArray); $p++) {
                $nextStop = $nextStopArray[$p];

                $walkToTheStop = false;

                // Few checks                   
                if ($p == 0) {
                    if ($nextStop != 0) {
                        $pathDuration = 2;                          

                        if ($lineToThisStop[$activeNode] != $rows["route_id"]) {
                            $pathDuration = $pathDuration * 2;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $walkToTheStop = true;

                    $pathDuration = 1;                          
                }

                // If that's shortest path from ActiveNode to nextStop insert it into it's time array (time to get to that stop)
                if (($pathDuration + $time[$activeNode]) < $time[$nextStop]) {
                    $time[$nextStop] = $pathDuration + $time[$activeNode];

                    array_push_key($previousNode, $nextStop, $activeNode);

                    // Some aditional records (5000 means "you must walk to that stop")
                    if ($walkToTheStop) {
                        $lineToThisStop[$nextStop] = 5000;
                    } else {
                        $lineToThisStop[$nextStop] = $rows["route_id"];
                    }
                }
            }           
        }

        // Traži slijedeću stanicu (vrh) s najmanjom vrijednosti        
        $lowestValue = 10000 + 1;
        for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($allStops); $j++) {
            if ($time[$allStops[$j]] < $lowestValue) {
                $lowestValue = $time[$allStops[$j]];                        
                $activeNode = $allStops[$j];

                // Record it's position so I can unset it later
                $activeNodePosition = $j;
            }
        }

        // Unset the active node from the array - so loop before will be shorter every time for one node/stop
        unset($allStops[$activeNodePosition]);
        $allStops = array_values($allStops);

        // If you get to the end stop, feel free to break out of the loop
        if ($activeNode == $endStop) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // How long did it take?
    $timeM = microtime(); $timeM = explode(' ', $timeM); $timeM = $timeM[1] + $timeM[0]; $finish = $timeM;

    $total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
    echo 'Total time '.$total_time.' seconds.'."<br />";
?>

<?php require_once("../includes/close_connection.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Micro-optimisations, but **don't** do:

```
for ($p = 0; $p < sizeof($nextStopArray); $p++) { 
   ...
}
```

calculate the sizeof($nextStopArray) **before** the loop, otherwise you're doing the count every iteration (and this value isn't being changed)

```
$nextStopArraySize = sizeof($nextStopArray);
for ($p = 0; $p < $nextStopArraySize; ++$p) { 
   ...
}
```

There's a couple of places where this should be changed.

And if you're iterating several thousand times, ++$p is faster than $p++

But profile the function... find out which parts are taking the longest to execute, and look to optimise those.

**EDIT**

Get rid of array_push_key as a function, simply execute it inline... it's costing you an unnecessary function call otherwise

Build an array of all nodes from your database outside of the while(true) loop... retrieve all the data in a single SQL query and build a lookup array.

Replacing

```
for ($p = 0; $p < sizeof($nextStopArray); $p++) {
```

with

```
$nextStopArraySize = sizeof($nextStopArray);
$p = -1
while (++$p < $nextStopArraySize) { 
   ...
}
```

may also prove faster still (just check that the logic does loop through the correct number of times).

Comment: I heard about this ++p and p++ but I didn't believe it. Now I do :D Now it's approx. 2x faster with those three optimizations. Could you mention anything else?

Comment: Some of the optimisations that you hear about aren't correct, others are. The only way to separate truth from rumour is to test them yourself. I've tested a lot of methods over the years, and some are really worthwhile.

Comment: I did the query only once on the beginning...result? Regularly under 0.01 seconds :) (without memcached)

Comment: Let's hope your hosting provider is happier with that. You'll be using more memory, but only for a tiny fraction of the time.

Answer (score 2):

At a glance (you should really do some profiling, by the way), the culprit is the fact that you are executing a query for each graph node to find its neighbors:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT route_id, next_stop FROM db_stop_times WHERE stop_id = $activeNode", $connection);
```

If you have 1,700 nodes this is going to issue on the order of a thousand queries. Rather than hitting the database so often, cache these database results in something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/), and only fall back to the database on cache misses.

Answer (score 2):

> it's using too much resources

Which resource? (CPU? Memory? Network bandwidth? I/O load on the database server?)

```
while (true) {       
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT route_id, next_stop FROM db_stop_times WHERE stop_id = $activeNode", $connection);
```

If I am reading this right you are doing a database call for every node in every pathfinding attempt. Each of these calls will block for a little while waiting for the response from the database. Even if you have a fast database, that's bound to take a couple milliseconds (unless the database is running on the same server as your code). So I'd venture the guess that most of your execution time is spent waiting for replies from the database.

Moreover, should your database lack proper indexes, each query could do a full table scan ...

The solution is straightforward: Load db_stop_times into memory at application startup, and use that in-memory representation when resolving neighbour nodes.

Edit: Yes, an index on stop_id would be a proper index for this query. As for practical caching, I don't know PHP, but with something like Java (or C#, or C++, or even C) I'd use  a representation of the form

```
class Node {
    Link[] links;
}

class Link {
    int time;
    Node destination;
}
```

that would be a bit faster than memcached, but assumes you can comfortably fit the entire table in main memory. If you can't do that, I'd use a caching system like memcached.